# Namespaced models: uninitialized constant Member::Album::Image (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, models

I have 3 models - Member, Album, and Image.

The member.rb file is in the /app/models directory:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :albums
```

The album.rb file is in the /app/models/member directory:

```
class Member::Album < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :images
```

The image.rb file is in the /app/models/member/album directory:

```
class Member::Album::Image < ActiveRecord::Base
```

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
resources :members do

    resources :albums, :controller => 'members/albums' do

        resources :images, :controller => 'members/albums/images',:only => [:new, :create, :destroy] do
            get :edit, :on => :collection
            put :update, :on => :collection
        end
    end
end
```

But when I try to load '/members/1/albums' (and several other places), I get the error uninitialized constant Member::Album::Image.

I even tried adding:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/member/album)
```

and

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

to my config/application.rb file (and restarted the server) to make sure that all my files nested in the subdirectories within the 'app/models' folder are being loaded, yet I still get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't actually use namespaces in controllers/models. It's just a nested route. You're forcing Rails to use your namespaced controllers in your routes. Instead just use:

```
resources :members do
  resources :albums do
    resources :images, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy] do
      get :edit, :on => :collection
      put :update, :on => :collection
    end
  end
end
```

Then you don't need to bother with namespaces in your controllers or models at all.

**Note**: It's recommended that you don't nest routes more than 2-deep. You're currently at 3, which produces some pretty gnarly URLs like http://example.com/members/42/albums/100/images/new.